# Text color based on background brightness in Flutter without opacity

Tags: flutter, themes, darkmode

In a freshly generated Flutter project, there is a counter with this style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4. As you can see in the picture below, it has some minor opacity by default. In addition, if I modify the brightness to Brightness.dark in ThemeData, it adapts to the grey background by changing the font color to white automatically, but it still has some opacity. What I need is to have pure dark and pure light adaptively based on the background's brightness for Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.

[image]

Comment: You can use [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) to set colors for both light theme and dark theme.